# Spotify API - receive specific data

Tags: integration, spotify, libspotify

i would like to know if it is possible to receive the specific data:
 - the number of people who like a certain artist or album, in a certain place.

This way i will know that Metallica has 25,000 fans in Lisbon and/or Muse's album (The Resistance) has 2,000 fans in Barcelona.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported in the Spotify API. You can see all the features/endpoints [here](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/) and submit or vote for feature requests [here](https://github.com/spotify/web-api).

The closest existing functionality to what you're looking for is the `popularity` and `followers` on [Get an Artist](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/artists/get-artist/), but there is no location-based data.